# How to select CompanyName and number of its products?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to write a Linq query that will return, columns with `CompanyName` of `Supplier` and number of all products of this company. Can you help me?

So far I got this:

```
var company = from pro in db.Products
              join sup in db.Suppliers
                  on pro.SupplierID equals sup.SupplierID
              group pro by pro.SupplierID 
              into g
              select new { Name = g.Key, COUNT = g.Count() };
```

But this returns `SupplierID` not `CompanyName`. Database is Northwnd.

Comment: What are you not sure about?  Do you not know what this specific query does, so you aren't sure how to change it?

Comment: It returns SupplierID, and I want CompanyName from Supplier

Comment: I understand that part, but I am just trying to figure out if you understand what the entire query is actually doing.

Comment: `group pro by pro.SupplierID` is a bit unclear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use group join (i.e. *join...into*) to join suppliers with products and get all products of supplier in group:

```
from s in db.Suppliers
join p in db.Products
   on s.SupplierID equals p.SupplierID into g
select new {
   s.CompanyName,
   ProductsCount = g.Count()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following compiles and runs with Linq-for-objects. I can't vouch for whether Linq-to-SQL will cope.

```
var company = from sup in db.Suppliers
              select new
              {
                  Name = sup.CompanyName,
                  COUNT = db.Products
                      .Where(pro => pro.SupplierID == sup.SupplierID)
                      .Count()
              };
```